# C++ MovieList array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

I'm still a bit stuck on another part on my assignment.

Here is what the prompt is asking:

> Now you can modify the LoadMovies function to create a MovieList
>   object and add each of the Movie objects to it. The function
>   LoadMovies should return a pointer to the MovieList object. That means
>   you need to create the MovieList object dynamically and on the heap.
>
> Change the main function and store the returned MovieList pointer in a
>   variable. To test if everything works as expected, you can use the
>   PrintAll function of the MovieList object.

Here is my code so far:

```
class MovieList {

public:
    Movie* movies;
    int last_movie_index;
    int movies_size;
    int movie_count = 0;

MovieList(int size) {
    movies_size = size;
    movies = new Movie[movies_size];
    last_movie_index = -1;
}

~MovieList() {
    delete [] movies;
}

int Length() {
    return movie_count;
}

bool IsFull() {
    return movie_count == movies_size;
}

void Add(Movie const& m)
{
    if (IsFull())
    {
        cout << "Cannot add movie, list is full" << endl;
        return;
    }

    ++last_movie_index;
    movies[last_movie_index] = m;
}

void PrintAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < movie_count; i++) {
        movies[last_movie_index].PrintMovie();
    }
}

};

void ReadMovieFile(vector<string> &movies);
void LoadMovies();

enum MovieSortOrder
{
    BY_YEAR = 0,
    BY_NAME = 1,
    BY_VOTES = 2
};

int main()
{
    LoadMovies();

    // TODO:
    // You need to implement the Movie and MovieList classes and
    // the methods below so that the program will produce
    // the output described in the assignment.
    //
    // Once you have implemented everything, you should be able
    // to simply uncomment the code below and run the program.

    MovieList *movies = LoadMovies();

    //    // test methods for the Movie and MovieList classes
        //PrintAllMoviesMadeInYear(movies, 1984);
        //PrintAllMoviesWithStartLetter(movies, 'B');
        //PrintAllTopNMovies(movies, 5);

        //delete movies;
    return 0;
}

void LoadMovies()
{
    vector<string> movies;
    ReadMovieFile(movies);

    string name;
    int year;
    double rating;
    int votes;

    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++)
    {
        istringstream input_string(movies[i]);
        getline(input_string, name, '\t');
        input_string >> year >> rating >> votes;
        Movie movie (name, year, votes, rating);
        movie.PrintMovie();
    }
}
```

Now where I'm stuck at is where the professor asks me to modify the LoadMovies in the prompt and turn it into a pointer. I'm drawing blanks. Also for some reason if I try to compile it says:

```
C:\Users\Andy\Documents\C++ Homework\MovieStatisticsProgram\MovieStatsProgram.cpp:163: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     MovieList *movies = LoadMovies();
                                    ^
```

Comment: In C++ "arrays" are not dynamic (they don't change after creation). They can be *dynamically allocated*.

Comment: Your instructions say to make an array of Movie objects, but you have created an array of ints instead.

Comment: Hey scott, can you explain to me what you mean? So should I have done movies = new Movie[movies_size] and instead of *int movies it should be *Movies movies?

Answer (score 0):

The order of your constructor is wrong

```
MovieList(int size) {
    movies = new int[movies_size];  // movies_size hasn't been initialized yet!
    movies_size = size;
    last_movie_index = -1;
}
```

It should be

```
MovieList(int size)
:  movies_size{size}, movies{new int[size]}, last_movie_index{0}
{}
```

Though as @ScottMcP-MVP noted your array should be

```
Movie* movie;
```

So your constuctor would be

```
MovieList(int size)
:  movies_size{size}, movies{new Movie[size]}, last_movie_index{0}
{}
```

**Some advice for getting started on the remaining functions**

`Length` function will return how many are current used from `last_movie_index`.

`IsFull` will check if `last_movie_index == movies_size - 1`

`Add` will need to use `last_movie_index` to figure out what element in your array to store the movie.

`PrintAll` will have to iterate from `[0]` to `[movie_count]` and print out each element.

Your `Add` function would look something like

```
void MovieList::Add(Movie const& m)
{
    if (IsFull())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot add movie, list is full" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    movies[last_movie_index] = m;   // assigns a copy to your array
    ++last_movie_index;             // Increment the movie index
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have a couple of more questions...I'm a little stuck on Add with the algorithm needed to insert into the next available element in the array, and as Scott stated earlier up, since my professor is asking for an array of Movie objects would it be movies = new Movie[movie_size] instead?

Comment: @andayn Yes you would have an array of `Movie`, you will have to define your `Movie` class. Please see my edit regarding the `Add` function.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much but can you reread my thread and help me out with my new problem? Working with pointers is killing me.

Comment: *"reread my thread and help me out with my new problem"* Instead of doing this, Stack Overflow is really meant to answer one question at a time. If you have another specific question, you may make a new post describing that question, and posting the small relevant snippet of code that describes the problem.

Comment: sry, I had no intention of posting my comment. I actually had a good example with comparing addresses from stack and heap, but after looking at the definition from the cpp reference I was a bit confused myself. They don't specificaly say that "new" creates the object on the heap, which was the point I was trying to make. Hence away with the answer.